# Is it possible Canvas toDataUrl return the same string across all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am observing that Canvas.toDataUrl is returning different value across browsers. Is it possible that I Canvas.toDataURL method return the same string across all browsers?(whether using client code or server code).

An Empty canvas in FireFox,

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMYAAAA3CAYAAABXVTXhAAAApklEQVR4nO3TMQEAIAzAsPk3DQLWH45EQZ/OAZZ5HQA/MgYEY0AwBgRjQDAGBGNAMAYEY0AwBgRjQDAGBGNAMAYEY0AwBgRjQDAGBGNAMAYEY0AwBgRjQDAGBGNAMAYEY0AwBgRjQDAGBGNAMAYEY0AwBgRjQDAGBGNAMAYEY0AwBgRjQDAGBGNAMAYEY0AwBgRjQDAGBGNAMAYEY0AwBgRjQDAGhAtrCYfA7BeW0wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

An Empty canvas in Chrome,

data:image/png;base64,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

Comment: Can you post your "observation"?

Comment: What do you mean "using server code"?

Comment: There are a number of factors that could affect how a PNG might be represented.  For one, even though it is a lossless format, you can specify compression "levels". I don't know about the algorithm's internals, but some PNG compressors allow you to iterate through the compression algorithm until some max iteration or it cannot compress any more, whereas some tools that allow you to save an image in PNG format may just run through the compression algorithm once (or so).

Comment: I have some suspicion it might actually be different in metadata but I'm too lazy to confirm that at the moment.